# Review (on meta) doesn't hide reviewed posts?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta, review

Just poking through /review on Meta quickly made me aware that after reviewing posts in any of the sections, and then revisiting the sections later wouldn't remove the posts from the tabs.

Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

#### EDIT:

Does the hiding-posts feature only work after acquiring the [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) badge?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this; if I review a post, and refresh the page, that post is hidden. When I visit another page (e.g. the front page, or a question page), and I return back to the review page, those hidden posts are still hidden.

Comment: I have the opposite - regardless of how many times I try to review the posts, they aren't removed, irregardless of how I return to the page (refresh, clicked tab, clicked "review", etc.)

Comment: I think you may need Strunk & White first. I have that badge on SO, and below the progress stats it shows the text "Hiding reviewed and closed posts". It doesn't show that on any other site for me. Although it might just be a coincidence...

Comment: @Brandon: I wondered if that was the case, as I have both Strunk & White and Copy Editor on SO, but neither here on MSO.

Comment: That could be the difference: I have those badges on MSO too, and reviewed posts are hidden from my view.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem on english.stackexchange, on probably a bit under 20% of visits. It leads to strange behavior with the "reviewed" counter (going up then back down).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need Strunk & White first.

[image]

I have verified this by reviewing and refreshing on a site where I have S&W and a site where I don't.

Comment: I feel like it ought to be more specific on what that means.

Answer (score 4):

We **do not** track and review progress until you become a "trusted" reviewer.

To do that you need the "Strunk & White" badge.

We are fine with you to experiment with the review page prior, but want to make sure the people who can "remove" posts from the page are people we trust to edit. I explained a bit more about this decision here: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/review-early-review-often/